# How to modify a variable that pass to an active sheet in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

My UIView needs to have an object pass to it before it can show as an active sheet. The object pass into it depends on the button that the user has clicked. That's why i wrote some code like this.

```
struct DetailInfoView: View {
    
    var cat: Cat

@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
@State var activeSheet: DetailViewActiveSheet?

@State var selectedFood: Food?

var body: some View {
   ZStack {
   ForEach(foods, id:\.self) {food in
                                    Button(action: {
                                        selectedFood = food
                                        activeSheet = .foodDetailView
                                    }, label: {
                                        Text(food.name).font(.caption2).padding(.top, -5.0)                                             
                                        })
                                    }
    }
    }.sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
        switch item {
        case .foodDetailView:
            FoodDetailView(food: self.selectedFood!)
        }
    }
}
```

I then find that even I have set selectedFood in the button action, it is forever nil and cause exception. Why it is the case?

FoodDetailView has nothing special.

```
struct FoodDetailView: View {

 var food: Food

  var body: some View {
     Text(food.name)
  }
}
```

I have another view that will show all my FoodDetailView. Whenever I change the var food to @binding var food of my FoodDetailView, it complains.

```
TabView() {
        ForEach(modelData.foods) { food in
            FoodDetailView(food: food)
        }
    }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

Maybe to clarify my question --- it should be:

1. I have multiple active sheets. That's why the .sheet will receive the item $activeSheet so that I know which other view should be shown.
2. For each of the View to be shown, they may need custom items. The items can only be created when the user click on the button. However, it appears that the .sheet and the related codes are created when the view is created, hence caused the exception. There are suggestion telling that I should use @binding here.
3. If I use @binding to the variable selectedFood, then may I know how to create the FoodDetailView() if I do not have any binding food variables in other views? For example, I have a list of Food Items, and I use a for loop just loop and create the FoodDetailView. In this case, when I loop the Food Item list, it is not a binding variable.

So I think my question is --- How to make those View created in .sheet() can be created on the fly?

Comment: Your `item` should be `self.selectedFood`, ie. model, not the view.

Comment: Can you please share `DetailViewActiveSheet` model?

Comment: enum DetailViewActiveSheet: Identifiable {
 case FoodView
 case AudioView
 
 var id:Int {
  hashValue
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your View: FoodDetailView ?
FoodDetailView(food: self.selectedFood!) is initiated when DetailInfoView appear.

I think you can edit like this :

```
struct DetailInfoView: View {

var cat: Cat

@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
@State var activeSheet: DetailViewActiveSheet?

@State var selectedFood: Food = Food() //just init even as empty

var body: some View {
   ZStack {
    ForEach(foods, id:\.self) {food in
       Button(action: {
          selectedFood = food
          activeSheet = .foodDetailView
       }, label: {                   
          Text(food.name).font(.caption2).padding(.top, -5.0)                                             
       })
       }
    }
}.sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
    switch item {
    case .foodDetailView:
        FoodDetailView(food: self.selectedFood)
    }
}
}
```

And remove @Binding I put earlier in FoodDetailView

Comment: FoodDetailView has nothing special. Updated. What do you mean by pass as Binding? How to do that?

Comment: It does not work. It is because there are other parts of my code that will just create a food object and load the FoodDetailView. Covert that to binding will cause the other parts fail :( Actually, I got confused with the 'binding' variables.

Comment: Can I create FoodDetailView on the fly whenever the user click the button, instead of as you said, when DetailInfoView appear?

Comment: Why are you using selectedFood as Optional ? This is what's causing your exception.

Comment: Your are telling your view that selectedFood is there with ! when it's not. :)

Comment: Updated my question. Hope that is clearer :(

Comment: Yeah forget about the Binding, I misread the problem earlier ^^
But try what I updated by not setting selectedFood Optional :)

Answer (score 0):

The `item` is what transferred into `sheet` block, so your design should be aligned to

```
}.sheet(item: $selectedFood) { item in
    switch item {
    case .foodDetailView:
        FoodDetailView(food: item)
    }
}
```

in this case `item` contains `selectedFood` once it has set.

Comment: I will have multiple sheet, that need to use item to do switching.

Comment: then you enum case with associated values, `item` should be only one.

Comment: Yes, and that's why i enumerate the active sheet, not the "food"

Comment: No, I meant your item should be `case .foodDetailView(let food)`, ie. enum with associated model... two states will not work in this case - you have to have single item for selection.